# Data from serial port of Capnomac ULTIMA

Tags: serial-port

A colleague of an animal surgery clinic has a rather old device that measures respiration gasses. This device has a serial port that can be used to get measured data to a computer.

[image]
[image]

Section 12 of the user manual (that can easily be found online) describes the communication protocol clearly with

- transmission rate 1200 b/s
- 8 data bits, no parity
- 1 stop bit

Although I have tried a USB-serial cable and a plain old serial cable with different *serial monitors*, I'm not able to capture any data from the device. I suspect that the device is not sending any data at all, but there seems to be no way to turn *serial transmission* on. Maybe it is broken, but I want to be sure.

**Question:** What is the most basic way to test whether or not any data is sent over the serial output?

I can connect my MacBook through the USB-Serial cable and an old Windows 7 laptop though the plain serial cable to the machine.

### Edit:

Here is a table for the serial pins

[image]

Comment: You should be able to measure the voltages with a multimeter. If not, you can buy something like this: [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=RS-232+Mini-Tester+with+LED+Indicators+DB-25#safe=active&q=RS-232+Mini-Tester+with+LED+Indicators+DB-25)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp This is indeed a good idea. I have of course a multimeter and I'm sure I can take an RS232 cable apart to test voltages.

Comment: Also, you _might_ need to "null" the cable - Tx and Rx pins are crossed. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem).

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I have added a diagram for the serial pins. Is it possible to tell whether I have to null the cable. It looks like the diagram is equal to the left side of the table in the wiki page you linked.?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it needs a crossover. So you have Tx pin (2) of device to Rx pin (3) of PC. Also, you need GND pins (7) connected to each other. If data is uni-directional, you can probably get away with just those 2 wires. Note, if PC end is DB9, RX pin is 2, so you want Tx (2) device to Rx (2) pc. And GND (7) device to GND (5) pc.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp OK, I need some days to test this as I'm not having access to the machine all the time. Thanks for leading me through and giving hints what to try!